# OnChange : change value trough Combo box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, combobox

im nubie in javascript and jquery.
i wanna change value of my "tipe" <-(variable) trough combo box

this is the script :

```
tipe = 'report-reg'; //this var that i wanna change
        $(document).ready(function () { //this is javascript for chart
            // prepare the data
            var theme = 'classic';

            var source =
            {
                 datatype: "json",
                 datafields: [
                     { name: 'reqtime', type: 'date'},
                     { name: 'jumlah'}
                ],
                url: 'include/data_chart/data-reg-day.php?type='+tipe //tipe load value from combobox
            };
```

this is the combo box html :

```
<form method="get" action="" name="combobox">
<div>
<select id="combobox" name="combo-box" onchange="tipe=this.value">
    <option>Select report tipe</option>
    <option value="report-reg-perday">Per-day Report</option>
    <option value="report-reg-perweek">Per-week Report</option>
    <option value="report-reg-permonth"> Per-Month Report</option>
</select>
 <div style="width:100%; height:500px" id="jqxChart"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

sorry if my post mess.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
$( "#combobox" ).change(function() {
    tipe = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#combobox').on('change', function() {
    tipe= this.value;
});
```